# WooCommerce loop start

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to add:

```
<h1><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'blankslate' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
```

At the beginning of the `loop-start.php` with an IF query to show if the user used the:

```
<?php get_product_search_form(); ?>
```

Then show the above snippet but if they navigated to the shop page do not include the:

```
<h1><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'blankslate' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
```

I am not sure on the best approach?

Comment: there's no guarantee but you can check for `$_GET['post_type']` if the value is `product`.

Comment: or you can edit in your theme template the file `product-searchform.php` and add a hidden input field... then you can check that through `$_GET`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In most themes you should already have a "Search results for X" page title.